# Precision on wget -r

Tags: macos, wget

This command worked as expected (see top folder in the image):

[image]

```
 wget -P ~/Downloads -r -A pdf http://www.college-de-france.fr/site/antoine-compagnon/
```

except it started retrieving other folders not specified in the url (the other folders, such as ressources-humaines).

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to add the `--no-parent` (`-np` for short) option. This ensures that it'll only descend into directories, never go somewhere else.